# Get introduced [linkedin] like

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j with people and companies as nodes and friend_of/works_at relationship between these.
I would like to know how to implement a get introduced to a second degree connection that linked in uses. The idea is to get your second degree connections at the company you wish to apply. If there are these second degree connections, then you would like to know who among your 1st deg connections can introduce y*ou to these 2nd deg connections.

For this I'm trying this query :

```
START from = node:Nodes(startNode), company = node:Nodes(endNode)
MATCH from-[:FRIEND_OF]->f-[:FRIEND_OF]-fof-[:WORKS_AT]->company
WHERE not(fof = from) and not (from-[:FRIEND_OF]->fof)
RETURN distinct f.name, fof.name, company.name
```

But, this returns duplicate friend of friend names (fof.name), since the distinct is applied on all the parameters that are returned as a whole. It could be like I have friends X and Y who are both connected to Z who works at company C. This way, I get both X-Z-C and Y-Z-C. But, I want to apply distinct on Z, such that I get either X-Z-C or Y-Z-C or maybe a list/collection/aggregate of all friends that connect to Z. This could like ["X","Y"..]->Z How should I modify my query?

Comment: Please create a sample database for us to play with, at console.neo4j.org

Comment: and what you want to return when you will have a situation like `X-Z-C and X-Y-C`

Comment: @ulkas
["X"] -> ["Y"]
["X"] -> ["Z"] 
Implying that X can connect me with Y and Z separately.

Comment: can't you just ommit the company.name in the return clause? you know that value anyway. than you might get what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=s1m14g

```
start joe=node:node_auto_index(name = "Joe") 
match joe-[:knows]->friend-[:knows]->friend_of_friend 
where not(joe-[:knows]-friend_of_friend) 
return collect(friend.name), friend_of_friend.name
```